# Refering to the same (alphabetically "numbered") footnote more than once

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, footnotes, counters

Following my [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30602/6102) concerning the change of numbering in footnote to temporally be alphabetical, I'm trying to merge this with the possibility to refer various time to the same footnote as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bette/10110#10110). I tried this :

```
       %---alpha footnotes

   \newenvironment{alphafootnotes}
     {\par\edef\savedfootnotenumber{\number\value{footnote}}
      \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}}
     {\par\setcounter{footnote}{\savedfootnotenumber}}


   %---refer to same footnote more than ounce

\newcommand{\footlabel}[2]{%
    \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
    \footnotetext[\thefootnote]{%
        \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
        \refstepcounter{footnote}\label{#1}%
        #2%
    }%
    $^{\ref{#1}}$%
}

\newcommand{\footrefa}[1]{%
    $^{\ref{#1}}$%
}

\newcounter{savefootnote}
```

But the new `\footlabel` command inside the newly defined environment seems to enter in conflict ( missing number ... treated as zero )? Any help?

Another part of my question would be redefining the style of the footnote numbering (that is: obtain *italic*, alphabetical "numbering" of the footnote)

The third and final question is: Is there a package managing all theses footnotes tunings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way to refer to a previously written footnote is to define

```
\newcommand{\footnoteref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}
```

and put a `\label` command in the footnote with multiple calls:

```
text\footnote{The footnote text\label{somelabel}} and again
the same footnote number\footnoteref{somelabel}
```

If you want italic letters, just change the code in the definition of `alphafootnotes`: instead of

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
```

write

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alph{footnote}}}
```

Consider the **bigfoot** or **manyfoot** packages for multiple footnote sets.