# Starting Numbering of Footnotes in Minipage at 1

Tags: numbering, footnotes, minipage

If you don't use any additional code, the footnotes in the minipage environment will continue with the number of the last footnote + 1. Is it possible to start footnotes with an arabic 1 again in a minibox when there occurred a number of footnotes before?

If you use 'alphanotes' of egreg [Change footnote "numbering" temporarily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/change-footnote-numbering-temporarily), there is an alphabetic numbering in the text and an arabic numbering in the footnote section.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article} %Aber noch mal wegen Subsublines und so schauen

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am Mac

\let\thempfootnote\thefootnote

% ---------
\newenvironment{alphafootnotes}
  {\par\edef\savedfootnotenumber{\number\value{footnote}}
   \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
   \setcounter{footnote}{0}}
  {\par\setcounter{footnote}{\savedfootnotenumber}}
%------------

\begin{document}

This is a document.\footnote{\dots}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.42\textwidth}%\centering
\begin{alphafootnotes}
Example.\footnotemark{}\footnotetext{\label{foot:1}Vgl. Quellenangabe, S. 234.}
Example.\footnotemark{}\footnotetext{\label{foot:2}Vgl. Quellenangabe, S. 234.}
\end{alphafootnotes}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not understanding the problem. Could you try to better explain it? How do you want the footnotes in a minipage numbered, alphabetically or with arabic numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need to have arabic numbers (what I included now).

Comment: Isn't `\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}` sufficient? Using `\footnote` in the minipage, of course.

Comment: By default minipage footnotes always start from 1, they do not carry on from the previous.

Comment: @egreg, it is enough. I don't know how I got to my strange "mwe". Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the purpose of the macros you tried to adapt. For your case it's sufficient to say

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
```

and use `\footnote` normally in the minipage.

Example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article} %Aber noch mal wegen Subsublines und so schauen

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am Mac

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

This is a document.\footnote{\dots}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.42\textwidth}%\centering
Example.\footnote{\label{foot:1}Vgl. Quellenangabe, S. 234.}
Example.\footnote{\label{foot:2}Vgl. Quellenangabe, S. 234.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

For preparing the image I reduced the text height (not shown in the code). Are you sure that `applemac` is the right encoding? If you use TeXShop, you can (and should) set the input encoding to UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: what if I'm using symbols? How to convert mpfootnote to symbol?

Comment: @avsej `\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}` instead of `\arabic{mpfootnote}`

Comment: Personally I find `\setcounter{mpfootnote}{1}` very useful.