# LaTeX footnotes won't change

Tags: pdftex, formatting, footnotes

I'm at the last stages of this text, and my goal is to insert a footnote inside a user-defined enumerate environment that is in two-column text. The footnote should appear as a red asterisk and the footnote text should span both columns.

In the MWE below, I've managed to get part of the way there. My two-column text works and the footnote spans both columns. The footnote counter behaves as expected (see solution presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30602/change-footnote-numbering-temporarily?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but it refuses to change to symbols (or letters - I've tried everything I can think of) or colors. In fact, in this MWE, the color of both footnotes is red (the new color); in my actual file, the color of both is blue (the original color). Additionally, the last paragraph of the footnote has something that looks like 1.5 or double spacing - and I can't correct it.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside, final, openright, c6paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[inner=0.3in, outer=0.3in, top=0.50in, bottom=0.35in, bindingoffset=0.25in, foot = 0.20in, includefoot, 
    footskip = 10pt, textheight = 5.4in, headsep=0.05in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{parskip}                        
\usepackage[flushmargin, splitrule, symbol*]{footmisc}  
\usepackage{enumitem}                       
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, hyperindex=true]{hyperref} 

% For footnotes: 
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\raisebox{0.30\baselineskip}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle(\@arabic\c@footnote)}}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\dimen\footins}{0.85\textheight}%
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{AE0000} 
\newcommand{\cdr}{\color{darkred}}


%% For the rubrics that are double-numbered
\newlist{bienumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlistdepth{4}
\setlist[bienumerate, 1]{%
  label=\arabic*\additionallabel.,
  wide,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\additionallabel}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\biitem}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{ (#1)}%
  }%
  \item
}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\justifying

Previous text\footnote{With a footnote}.

\begin{bienumerate}[itemsep=-0.75ex, leftmargin=0ex, itemindent=1em, parsep=3pt, resume]
\biitem[156] 
\newcounter{tempfootnote}
\setcounter{tempfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\cdr \fnsymbol{footnote}}
In domibus interprovincialibus, nationalibus, et internationalibus Ordinis, pro absolutione 
divini Officii in choro vel in communi, adhibendum est calendarium proprium Ordinis universi, additis 
tantum festis propri\ae\ ecclesi\ae\ (n.~42) necnon festis de quibus n.\ 50.\footnote{{\tiny{
(154). In seminariis et collegiis clericorum di\oe cesanis, Religiosisi commissis, pro 
absolutione divini Officii in communi, sive a clericis sive a Religiosis qui una cum clericis Officium in communi 
dicunt, adhibendum est calendarium loci, additis festis ecclesi\ae\ seminarii vel collegii (n.~45 codicis rubricarum), 
data insuper facultate adiungendi festa Tituli necnon sancti Fundatoris Religiosorum quibus regimen seminarii 
commissum est. 

(155). In seminariis et collegiis clericorum interdi\oe cesanis, regionalibus, nationalibus, et internationalibus, 
pro absolutione divini Officii in communi, adhibendum est calendarium Ecclesi\ae\ univers\ae, additis festis 
Patroni principalis nationis, regionis seu provinci\ae\ sive ecclesiastic\ae\ sive civilis, di\oe cesis, oppidi seu 
civitatis, anniversario Dedicationis ecclesi\ae\ cathedralis di\oe cesis et aliis festis actu feriatis, si qu\ae\ sint, 
necnon festis ecclesi\ae\ seminarii vel collegii (n.~45 codicis rubricarum).  

Si autem huiusmodi seminariorum regimen Religiosis commissum sit, calendarium Ecclesi\ae\ univers\ae\ 
adhibendum est etiam a Religiosis qui una cum clericis Officium in communi absolvunt, data tamen facultate 
addendi festa tituli Ordinis seu Congregationis necnon sancti Fundatoris Religiosorum quibus regimen 
seminarii commissum est. %
}}}
\setcounter{footnote}{\value{tempfootnote}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\end{bienumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be easier just to format the footnote as text then add it to \footins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside, final, openright, c6paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[inner=0.3in, outer=0.3in, top=0.50in, bottom=0.35in, bindingoffset=0.25in, foot = 0.20in, includefoot, 
    footskip = 10pt, textheight = 5.4in, headsep=0.05in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{parskip}                        
\usepackage[flushmargin, splitrule, symbol*]{footmisc}  
\usepackage{enumitem}                       
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, hyperindex=true]{hyperref} 

% For footnotes: 
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\raisebox{0.30\baselineskip}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle\textcolor{footnotemark}{(\thefootnote)}}}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\dimen\footins}{0.85\textheight}%
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{AE0000} 
\newcommand{\cdr}{\color{darkred}}
\colorlet{footnotemark}{darkred}

%% For the rubrics that are double-numbered
\newlist{bienumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlistdepth{4}
\setlist[bienumerate, 1]{%
  label=\arabic*\additionallabel.,
  wide,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\additionallabel}{}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\biitem}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{}%
  }{%
    \renewcommand{\additionallabel}{ (#1)}%
  }%
  \item
}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\justifying

Previous text\footnote{With a footnote}.


\begin{bienumerate}[itemsep=-0.75ex, leftmargin=0ex, itemindent=1em, parsep=3pt, resume]
\biitem[156] 
\newcounter{tempfootnote}
\setcounter{tempfootnote}{\value{footnote}} \setcounter{footnote}{0} 
\colorlet{footnotemark}{green} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
In domibus interprovincialibus, nationalibus, et internationalibus Ordinis, 
pro absolutione divini Officii in choro vel in communi, adhibendum est 
calendarium proprium Ordinis universi, additis tantum festis propri\ae\ 
ecclesi\ae\ (n.~42) necnon festis de quibus n.\ 50.\footnote{{\tiny{ (154). 
In seminariis et collegiis clericorum di\oe cesanis, Religiosisi commissis, 
pro absolutione divini Officii in communi, sive a clericis sive a Religiosis 
qui una cum clericis Officium in communi dicunt, adhibendum est calendarium 
loci, additis festis ecclesi\ae\ seminarii vel collegii (n.~45 codicis 
rubricarum), data insuper facultate adiungendi festa Tituli necnon sancti 
Fundatoris Religiosorum quibus regimen seminarii commissum est. 

(155). In seminariis et collegiis clericorum interdi\oe cesanis, 
regionalibus, nationalibus, et internationalibus, pro absolutione divini 
Officii in communi, adhibendum est calendarium Ecclesi\ae\ univers\ae, 
additis festis Patroni principalis nationis, regionis seu provinci\ae\ sive 
ecclesiastic\ae\ sive civilis, di\oe cesis, oppidi seu civitatis, 
anniversario Dedicationis ecclesi\ae\ cathedralis di\oe cesis et aliis festis 
actu feriatis, si qu\ae\ sint, necnon festis ecclesi\ae\ seminarii vel 
collegii (n.~45 codicis rubricarum).  

Si autem huiusmodi seminariorum regimen Religiosis commissum sit, calendarium 
Ecclesi\ae\ univers\ae\ adhibendum est etiam a Religiosis qui una cum 
clericis Officium in communi absolvunt, data tamen facultate addendi festa 
tituli Ordinis seu Congregationis necnon sancti Fundatoris Religiosorum 
quibus regimen seminarii commissum est. \par% 
}}} 
\setcounter{footnote}{\value{tempfootnote}} 
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\end{bienumerate}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indentation of "(154)"?

Comment: You are amazing. I'd like to know the "why," but this takes care of my issues.

Comment: \biitem (154) places the number right justified inside a label.  (155) is indented using \parindent.